# What are the picklist values for ProcessInstanceNode.NodeStatus?

Tags: picklist, approval-process, approval-step

According to the API documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstancenode.htm) the statuses of of an approval instance node are Started, Pending, or Approved.

However, the documentation for ProcessInstance.Node contains the same details, but the actual values for the protected picklist are:

- Approved
- Rejected
- Recalled
- Fault
- Pending
- Hold
- Reassigned
- Submitted
- NoResponse

Am I to assume the same for ProcessInstanceNode.NodeStatus? How can I check to see what the values are myself for future reference when dealing with protected picklists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run through the following code to see the values:

```
for (PicklistEntry entry : ProcessInstanceNode.NodeStatus.getDescribe().getPicklistValues())
    system.debug(entry);
```

Results:

> - Approved
> - Rejected
> - Recalled
> - Fault
> - Pending
> - Hold
> - Reassigned
> - Submitted
> - NoResponse

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I will. My current reputation value is witholding me from accepting it as the correct answer at the moment.

Comment: You should always be able to accept, though rep may prevent you from voting up. @Kai